# How to change array or json based on their value?

Tags: php, arrays, json

i have an json and i changed to array.

```
$asm1n = json_decode($asm_1);
print_r ($asm1n);
```

the result is

> Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 )

my problem is how to change it value based static value :
if it, 1 change to orange, 2 change apple, 3 change mango automatically

currently the value is like this in json:

```
["2","3"]
```

what i want to know how to make condition if the value like above it auto change to :

```
["apple","mango"]
```

i try use below code  but i thing is wrong :

```
if ($asm1n == ["1","2","3"]){
    $asm1n = "["orange","apple","mango"]";
}
```

this all data come from database, it might have value like this ["2","3"] , ["1","2","3"], ["1","3"].

how to change the number to the value like i said before? automatically or by if condition?

Comment: Please read - https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$asm1n = ["2", "3"];

$data = array();
foreach( $asm1n as $key => $value ) {
  if ( "1" === $value ) {
    $data[] = "orange";
  } elseif ( "2" === $value ) {
    $data[] = "apple";
  } elseif ( "3" === $value ) {
    $data[] = "mango";
  }
}

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through your array and change it accordingly.

```php
$fruits = [
    1 => 'orange',
    2 => 'apple',
    3 => 'mango'
];

foreach($asm1n as &$value){
    foreach($fruits as $key => $fruit){
        if($value==$key){
            $value = fruit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, forgot to add &

Comment: You also don't need the inner loop. You can remove the inner `foreach` completely and just replace it with: `$value = $fruits[$value] ?? 'Invalid id';`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to ensure that you have the values and to use them to get your output

```
$myValues = [
    1 => "orange",
    2 => "apple",
    3 => "mango"
];

$rawValues = json_decode($asm_1);

$asm1n = [];

foreach ($rawValues as $value) {
    $asm1n[]=$myValues[$value];
}

print_r ($asm1n);
```